# c++ Generic space filtering exploit prevention

Tags: c++, url, whitespace

so currently I am making a game that has the functionality to grab specific info from the host site. The issue is I am not sure if exploiters could get around my space check (which would let exploiters change header data), Here is my check currently in c++

```
   char* siteaccess = aaa.get();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < aaa.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (aaa[i] != ' ')
            *siteaccess = aaa[i];
            siteaccess++;
```

currently I could not bypass the check myself so I think I am safe. But I am also a novice at c++ so I believe there is a way around it. I would like to figure out any potential workarounds before my game goes public, If this can be exploited please provide an example(this will help me fix it). Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you want to achieve. It looks like you are trying to modify a string based on white-spaces?

Comment: to Henning Koehler: I am modifying the string the user provides that makes a GET request to the url. The goal is that the user cannot make their url "https://example.com/ HTTP/1.1" and will get filtered to "https://example.comhttp/1.1" removing the space. This way the user cannot continue the rest of the request and modify headers, etc. because it will just 404 the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is not so much with bypassing your space-removal check in c++ (they cannot), but about finding a string without spaces that stuffs up your get request.

I'm not too familiar with code injection for GET requests, but my suggestion would be to use a library for building your request, as manually fiddling with it is very likely to leave you open to exploits. E.g. a tab character might have the same effect as a white-space?

Comment: thank you for the fast reply. I am glad that the check is not vulnerable to any bypasses/exploits.